# show webview from top in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am loading the `webpage` in `webview` android. Webpage contains one `editbox` at bottom. After loading webpage, focus is always going to that `editbox`. I can't get top views of webpage initially. I need to show the webpage from top after loading finished. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
});
```

Also you can use this for better performance (if you have only one web-page to display):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


 <ProgressBar
   android:indeterminate="true"
   android:visibility="visible" 
   .../>

 <WebView
  android:visibility="gone" 
   .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

and code:

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      showWebView(WebView view);
      }
    });
```

...

```
private static final int TIME_TO_DELAY = 200;

private void showWebView(WebView view){
  view.scrollTo(0,0);
  view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }, TIME_TO_DELAY);

}
```

Comment: view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
view.scrollTo(0,0);
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }, TIME_TO_DELAY);